# ANOVA over a list of dataframes and ignore dataframe where number of groups is too small

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes that consists chemistry information that compares the results between laboratories for around 30 analytes.  Each analyte is stored as a single dataframe within the list of dataframes

I have written a function that performs ANOVA over each dataframe which works except when the number of laboratories is less than 3. ANOVA should have a minimum of 3 groups for comparison. I am attempting to put in a condition (if statement) that identifies the analytes that do not meet the 3 laboratory requirement and then return NA and if does meet the requirement it goes aheads and undertakes the operation.

A sample of my list of dataframe below

```
list(Fe = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, `2` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(56.83, 56.54, 56.18, 56.5, 56.51, 
56.34), `4` = c(56.39, 56.43, 56.53, 56.31, 56.47, 56.35), `5` = c(56.32, 
56.29, 56.31, 56.32, 56.39, 56.32), `7` = c(56.48, 56.4, 56.54, 
56.43, 56.73, 56.62), `8` = c(56.382, 56.258, 56.442, 56.258, 
56.532, 56.264), `10` = c(56.3, 56.5, 56.2, 56.5, 56.7, 56.5), 
    `12` = c(56.11, 56.46, 56.1, 56.35, 56.36, 56.37)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame"), SiO2 = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, 
    `2` = c(7.63, 7.65, 7.73, 7.67, 7.67, 7.67), `3` = c(7.84, 
    7.69, 7.59, 7.77, 7.74, 7.64), `4` = c(7.67, 7.74, 7.62, 
    7.81, 7.66, 7.8), `5` = c(7.91, 7.84, 7.96, 7.87, 7.84, 7.92
    ), `7` = c(7.77, 7.83, 7.76, 7.78, 7.65, 7.74), `8` = c(7.936, 
    7.685, 7.863, 7.838, 7.828, 7.767), `10` = c(7.872684992, 
    7.851291827, 7.872684992, 7.722932832, 7.680146501, 7.615967003
    ), `12` = c(7.64, 7.71, 7.71, 7.65, 7.82, 7.68)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame"), Al2O3 = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, 
    `2` = c(2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.01, 2.02, 2), `3` = c(2.01, 2.01, 
    2, 2.02, 2.02, 2.03), `4` = c(2, 2.03, 1.99, 2.01, 2.01, 
    2.01), `5` = c(2.02, 2.02, 2.05, 2.03, 2.02, 2.03), `7` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `8` = c(2.053, 2.044, 2.041, 2.038, 
    2.008, 2.02), `10` = c(2.002830415, 2.021725042, 2.021725042, 
    1.983935789, 2.002830415, 2.021725042), `12` = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    TiO2 = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, `2` = c(0.07, 
    0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07), `3` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), `4` = c(0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07), `5` = c(0.07, 
    0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07), `7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), `8` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `10` = c(0.066721378, 
    0.066721378, 0.066721378, 0.066721378, 0.066721378, 0.066721378
    ), `12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
    ), class = "data.frame"), Sn = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, 
        `2` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA), `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `5` = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        `8` = c(0.004, 0.004, 0.002, 0.007, 0.003, 0.004), `10` = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

The code that works below

```
lab.Anova <- function(x,...){
  x <- gather(x, Determination_No) #convert the data to long format for Anova
  colnames(x) <- c("Lab_No", "Results") #Rename the columns
  LabLm <- lm(Results ~ as.factor(x$Lab_No), data = x) #Create a linear Model for Anova
  Lab.Aov <- anova(LabLm)
  Lab.Critical <- cbind(Lab.Aov, 'F Critical Value' = qf(1 - 0.05, Lab.Aov[1, 1], Lab.Aov[2, 1]))
  Lab.SDWithinLab <- round(sqrt(Lab.Critical[2,3]),digits = 4) #Assign the variance to a variable from ANOVA results
  Lab.SDBetweenLab <- round(sqrt(Lab.Critical[1,3]),digits = 4)
  list(Lab.SDWithinLab,Lab.SDBetweenLab)
}
```

I am trying to do a count for the number of labs then if >2 do the ANOVA test else return NA something like

```
lab.Anova <- function(x,...){
  x <- gather(x, Determination_No) #convert the data to long format for Anova
  colnames(x) <- c("Lab_No", "Results") #Rename the columns
  totlabs <-count(unique(x$Lab_No | x$Lab_No == !is.na ))
    if totlabs > 2
      LabLm <- lm(Results ~ as.factor(x$Lab_No), data = x) #Create a linear Model for Anova
      Lab.Aov <- anova(LabLm)
      Lab.Critical <- cbind(Lab.Aov, 'F Critical Value' = qf(1 - 0.05, Lab.Aov[1, 1], Lab.Aov[2, 1]))
      Lab.SDWithinLab <- round(sqrt(Lab.Critical[2,3]),digits = 4) #Assign the variance to a variable from ANOVA results
      Lab.SDBetweenLab <- round(sqrt(Lab.Critical[1,3]),digits = 4)
  
    else 
      Lab.SDWithinLab <- NA
      Lab.SDBetweenLab <- NA
  list(Lab.SDWithinLab,Lab.SDBetweenLab)
}
```

I am getting an error with totlabs as it does not like the | and !is.na

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following function :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

lab.Anova <- function(x,...){
  x <- gather(x, Determination_No) 
  colnames(x) <- c("Lab_No", "Results") 
  totlabs <- n_distinct(x$Lab_No[!is.na(x$Results)], na.rm = TRUE)
  if(totlabs > 2) {
    LabLm <- lm(Results ~ factor(Lab_No), data = x) 
    Lab.Aov <- anova(LabLm)
    Lab.Critical <- cbind(Lab.Aov, 'F Critical Value' = qf(1 - 0.05, Lab.Aov[1, 1], Lab.Aov[2, 1]))
    Lab.SDWithinLab <- round(sqrt(Lab.Critical[2,3]),digits = 4) 
    Lab.SDBetweenLab <- round(sqrt(Lab.Critical[1,3]),digits = 4)
  } else {
    Lab.SDWithinLab <- NA
    Lab.SDBetweenLab <- NA  
  }
  list(Lab.SDWithinLab,Lab.SDBetweenLab)
}

lapply(df, lab.Anova)
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I get "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Lab.SDWithinLab' not found"  I think this will not work if there are 2 labs? as the ANOVA in R will still run even though its not the intended use of ANOVA.  Having said that when there are only 2 labs R does return a message "In anova.lm(LabLm) :
  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable".  I am trying to get the count of labs for the analyte first to stop analyte from being performed .

Comment: @user3614197 Sorry, I had `Lab.SDWithinLab` in my global environment. Hence, it worked for me. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, I was getting stuck on how to pass the !is.na in the results column.